# Can left-hand side of assignment be an expression in Javascript

Tags: javascript, vue.js

why it doesn't work.
And it shows the Error

#### invalid left-hand side in assignment expression

*VueJs*

```
for (let i = 1; i <= this.properties.length; i++) {

    this.product.properties + `.property${i}` = '';

}‍‍‍‍‍‍
```

*data*

```
data () {
  return {
     product: {
       properties:{}
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: you can't perform an operation (`+`) before the `=`, to access a property an object dynamically you should always write `myObject[dynamicKeyString]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```js
this.product = {
  properties: {}
};

for (var i = 0, len = 10; i < len; i++) {
  this.product.properties["property" + i] = '';
}

console.log(this.product);
```

Answer (score 1):

product.properties[property${i}] = ''

Answer (score 0):

```
v left-hand side                            v right-hand side
this.product.properties + `.property${i}` = '';
```

In Javascript, on left-hand side of assigment operator must be something to which you can assign a value e.g. variable or object property. In your case there is addition expression there which is not valid.